# How can I visualize a set of lat/long datapoints on a map?

Tags: geolocation, geo

Found this site, http://www.batchgeo.com/ , but seems to require addresses.

I just have a long list of lat/long coordinates and would like to visualize on a map.

Comment: There are many, many ways to do it, depending upon what other tools you might have at your disposal. As it stands, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mapping APIs (Google Maps, Bing Maps, etc.) allow direct positioning of markers on their maps by lat/lon. For example:

http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?sp=point.47.68_-122.12_MyMarker&lvl=10

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding) to find the corresponding addresses for the coordinates.